# Power BI desktop cannot import data with Azure Cost Management Connector

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, cost-management

I recently started using the [Azure Cost Management connector for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-bi/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management). The idea is to get Azure consumption data to PBI and generate some reports. However, I'm getting the following error when trying to load the data:

> The user does not have any claims associated

[image: Screenshot]

I am using our organization's Enrollment Number and the Key. I tried the [Azure Consumption Insights connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-azure-consumption-insights) and it worked without an issue and I was able to import data into PBI desktop app.

Do we need to enable anything from our organization's Enterprise Agreement side of things, to be able to use the new connector? Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: Do you have access to the billing account (enrollment)? Is your account listed as a "Microsoft Account" or a "Work or School account" in the EA portal? Did you use OAuth 2.0 and sign in with your Azure AD account? That error sounds like incorrect auth method was used, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It looks like the new connector does not ask for a key when trying to import data from PBI desktop. It seems to be checking the user's role instead of asking for a key explicitly, whereas in Azure Consumption Insights one could import data just by having a Enrollment No. and Key. I will keep you posted.

Comment: The old EA key-based APIs are being deprecated. The new connector uses Resource Manager APIs, which use Azure AD. I added an answer with more details on how you should be able to address this. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Cost Management connector for Power BI uses Azure AD instead of the old EA API key. You should be prompted for credentials when you setup the connector. Here's the typical flow:

1. Get Data > Azure > Azure Cost Management
   [image: Power BI's Get Data dialog, with Azure Cost Management selected]
2. Click **Connect**
3. Select **Enrollment Number** for Enterprise Agreement accounts
4. Type or paste your enrollment number
5. Select the number of months you want to see
   [image: Azure Cost Management setup wizard asking for enrollment number]
6. Click **OK**
7. Sign in to your Azure AD account and click **Connect**
   [image: Sign in to Azure Active Directory]
8. Select the desired tables and click **Load**
   [image: Select the desired tables]

At this point, Power BI should load the data, which may take a while, depending on how much data you have.

I noticed that Power BI may select an existing Azure AD account in step 7, if you're already signed in. I suspect that's what you're facing. If that's the case, you can just click **Load** in step 8 above and ignore the preview error, then change the account you use by going to:

1. File > Options and settings > Data source settings
   [image: Open data source settings from the File menu]
2. Select **Azure Cost Management** and click **Edit Permissions...**
   [image: Data source settings dialog]
3. Click **Edit...**
   [image: Edit permissions dialog]
4. Click **Sign in as different user**, switch to an account that has read access to the enrollment, and then click **Save**
   [image: Sign in dialog]
5. Click **OK**, then **Close**

That should give you what you need. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Michael! Yes, that was the issue :)